# Linux - How to add incremental numbers to the middle of a filename?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I've been seeing a ton of answers that show how to add to the beginning or end of a file, but I'm looking to replace numbers in the middle of a file. I have, for example:

```
ShowName - S00E01 - Episode Name.mkv
ShowName - S00E02 - Episode Name.mkv
ShowName - S00E03 - Episode Name.mkv
```

I want to change the E01-E03 part to be something like E20 to E22, or similar, without modifying the rest of the filename.

Couldn't figure out how to do this using linux's "rename" call, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Linux utility `rename` is just a simple tool. A more advanced  tool using a regular expression is `perl-rename`, which usually installed separately. However it still will not solve your problem.

For anything more complicated, i usually resort to writing a small bash for loop.
E.g. this script should work for your problem:

```
# for every file ending with .mkv
for f in *.mkv; do
        # transform the filename using sed, so that character '|' character will separate episode number from the lest of the filename (so it can be extracted)
        # e.g. 
        # 'ShowName - S00E01 - Episode Name.mkv' will be 
        # 'ShowName - S00E|01| - Episode Name.mkv'
        # Then read such string to three variables:
        # prefix enum and suffix splitting on '|' character
        IFS='|' read -r prefix enum suffix < <(sed 's/\(.*S[0-9][0-9]E\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\)/\1|\2|\3/' <<<"$f");
        # newfilename consist of prefix, calculated episode number and the rest of the filename
        # i assumed you want to add 19 to episode number
        # it may be also a good idea to move files to another directory, to avoid unintentional overwriting of existing files
        # you may also consider using -n/--no-clobber or --backup options to mv
        newf="another_directory/${prefix}$(printf "%02d" "$((enum-1+20))")${suffix}"
        # move "$f" to "$newf"
        # filenames have special characters (spaces), so remember about qoutes 
        echo "'$f' -> '$newf'"
        mv -v "$f" "$newf"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use some other tools like `grep` to help you:

```
for f in *.mkv; do
  NUM=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po '(?<=E)[0-9]{2}')
  NEWNUM=$((NUM+20))
  fn=${f/E${NUM}/E${NEWNUM}}
  mv "$f" "$fn"
done
```

The rest should be easily done with shell's builtin string replacement functionality.